# Understanding Liferay Password Encryption

Tags: encryption, encoding, passwords, liferay, password-hash

About passwords encryption in liferay I found out that liferay is using
**PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000** algorithm by default which generates 160 bit hashes using 128,000 rounds.

And I can use the following types by applying them in my portal-ext.properties file

```
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=BCRYPT/10
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=MD2
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=MD5
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=NONE
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=SHA
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=SHA-256
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=SHA-384
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=SSHA
#passwords.encryption.algorithm=UFC-CRYPT
```

with default type "**PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000**" i found that every password is being generated starting with a prefix "AAAAoAAB9A"
 Like : "AAAAoAAB9ACpjEM1K54bHX0UMY+3AgeAX3n50ZGERRK6MpxC"

> I need to know that why every password is starting with this prefix while using the mentioned algorithm.

By using another algorithm "**BCRYPT/10**" i found out that my passwords are starting with "$2a$10" Like: "$2a$10$Xyx.o1kv1mIr8rtpr9sxwOP6AC9I/u7tAIlyfrzp8Vlqcek/CGdQ"

Some how i figured out that "10" in "$2a$10" the password is getting hashed with a salt with 10 rounds. is this correct or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: bcrypt doesn't use a linear rounds/iterations number, but rather a logarithmic cost factor. Also, liferay is open source, so you can simply look into the source code.

Comment: you are correct; bcrypt (and basically all KDFs) need to know the parameters before running, so that they know when to "stop" and compare. if that value is constant in your system, like it is with the pbkdf2 routine, you can strip that info and patch it back in later, but why bother?

Comment: @efxeekay You ask more than one question in one post. Please extract your second question into a new post - it helps people to focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: @ArtjomB looking into liferay code helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay uses **PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000** by default, the encrypted password is a combination of bytes of **"key size, number of rounds, salt and secret key bytes"** being placed in order in the bytebuffer and then Base64 encoding over the combination.

So the reason why there is a prefix "AAAAoAAB9A" in: "AAAAoAAB9ACpjEM1K54bHX0UMY+3AgeAX3n50ZGERRK6MpxC" is because this is the combination of key size and Number of rounds (i.e 160/128000) byte buffer which is being encoded as a whole into Base64. Changing the key size and number of rounds you will comeup with some different prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take your example :"AAAAoAAB9ACpjEM1K54bHX0UMY+3AgeAX3n50ZGERRK6MpxC"

Encode it from base64 to hex : "000000a0 0001f400 a98c4335 2b9e1b1d 7d14318f b7020780 5f79f9d1 91844512 ba329c42"

Encode 000000a0 from hex to decimal, you get 160 like the key size.

Encode 0001f400 from hex to decimal, you get 128000 like the iterations.

a98c4335 2b9e1b1d is your salt.

7d14318f b7020780 5f79f9d1 91844512 ba329c42 is the hashed password.