# LDAP password not authenticate in liferay

Tags: ldap

i have made LDAP integration with liferay Users got importing and displays in testLDAP users.but i could not make LDAP user LOGIN with liferay what am missing.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Test  whether connection is working by going to control panel->portal setting->authentication->ldap->Test LDAP connection
2. Check whether users are imported to liferay user_ table
3. Execute (Reindex all search indexes). under server administration->Resources-->Action
4. Check password encryption algorithm  for your liferay version (may be your  password encrypted in user_ table is different from algorithm liferay using)
   [Understanding Liferay Password Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898278/understanding-liferay-password-encryption)